# "php include" strange characters in the generator xml "'╗ ┐' ╗ ┐"

Tags: php, xml, output

The structure of this XML is corrupted because of "include" connection database.
As you can see, there are strange characters in the first line of the file (`'╗ ┐' ╗ ┐`).

However, they do not appear on the web, since they only appear when I use cmd.exe to `type` the file.  Here is a screenshot of the offending file:

[image]

Here's the URL of the file: 
http://web.wipix.com.br/aniversariantes.xml

In my PHP file, I have two "includes" in the files connection.php (connection to database) AND "serialize.php" to generate the XML.
This only works if I take out the "includes" and use everything on one page only.  How can I fix this?

Comment: I'd guess there is a Unicode [Byte Order Mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) at the beginning of one of the files. You won't be able to see it in the editor. What editor are you using? Does it have an option to *not* include a Byte Order Mark (BOM) when saving files?

Comment: Are you sure that your file is really encoded with ISO-8859-1, as the `<?xml?>` declaration says?

Comment: zneak, i'm header("content-type: text/xml;  charset=ISO-8859-1");

Comment: Matt Gibson I am using Dreamweaver yes he has the option to not include a Byte Order Mark (BOM) my xml is generated dynamically i'll try to take the "BOM" of the other two files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably your xml file is in UTF-8 format with BOM.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark

Remove offending 8 bytes or save your xml without BOM using a text editor.
If xml is dinamically generated, you have to modify the generation code.

Moreover, the BOM bytes seems encoded badly. Probably the xml was converted in a wrong way and BOM bytes were screwed up.

Comment: Thank the file that generates the xml did not have the "BOM" but the other two had

Answer (score 1):

That is a [byte order mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) (Unicode character U+FEFF) but it being displayed in an incorrect encoding. Since your document claims to be encoded as ISO-8859-1 there should not be a byte order mark.

Answer (score 0):

The odd stuff at the beginning could be a byte-order mark, but I'm not sure.
A byte-order mark is a byte sequence inserted at the beginning of a file used to indicate the [endianness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) of it, or whether the most significant byte comes first.

From your output, there are other weird characters (not text) in the file, so it is possible that the program inserted them in.